# Cant mock static functions with powermock-easymock-testng (non-maven project)

Tags: function, static, testng, easymock, powermock

To tell you first, i have tried and tried it again and now i need some help

Heres my code

```
package staticPkg;

public class Static {

 public static final String staticMethod() {
  System.out.println("Static method called");
  return "Static called";
 }

}
package staticPkg;

public class TargetClass {

 Static staticClass;
 public String callHere() {
  return Static.staticMethod();
 }

}

package staticPkg;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.testng.IObjectFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.ObjectFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@PrepareForTest({Static.class})
public class TestClass  {

 Static staticClass = null;

 @ObjectFactory
 public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
System.out.println("got object factory");

return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory();
 }

 @BeforeMethod
 public void setup() {
  System.out.println("print me");
  PowerMock.mockStatic(Static.class);
  staticClass = PowerMock.createMock(Static.class);

 }


 @Test
 public void testMe() {
  EasyMock.expect(Static.staticMethod()).andReturn("Mock called").anyTimes();
  PowerMock.replay(Static.class,staticClass);
  TargetClass tc = new TargetClass();
  String output = tc.callHere();
  PowerMock.verify(Static.class,staticClass);
  System.out.println(output);

 }
}
```

```
And heres the log
```

[Parser] Running:
  C:\MockWorkspace\Mock\temp-testng-customsuite.xml

```
got object factory
print me
Static method called
FAILED: testMe
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
 at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:521)
 at org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:499)
 at staticPkg.TestClass.testMe(TestClass.java:46)
... Removed 22 stack frames

===============================================
    staticPkg.TestClass
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Mock
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Help please, i have tried a variety of solutions, can't get it done.
Please can anyone try this code and correct it for success?
I get error in EasyMock.expect ...............

Got a work around at http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2006/10/12/doing-bytecode-kungfu-with-javassist.html
And it works
But wait..........I am stuck again
My testcase works fine when runs alone, but when run with Ant, it gives problem. Might be other test cases of different files are interfering.
I got the same error, when my individual test case was using @PrepareTest & easymock/powermock

[testng] ====================STATIC CALLED===========================
   [testng] javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClass
Loader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/symantec/mobius/aggregator/submission/SubmissionFactory"
   [testng]     at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1085)
   [testng]     at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1028)
   [testng]     at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:986)
   [testng]     at javassist.CtClass.toClass(CtClass.java:1110)

Answer (score 1):

Try extending from PowerMockTestCase. The TestNG support will also be updated in next version of PowerMock (1.4.9).

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same issue, and struggled a lot. Finally, found the following solution:

Another alternative is to set the `object-factory` to `org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory` in the TestNG suite.xml. Here is a sample suite file:

```
<suite name="dgf" verbose="10" object-factory="org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory">
    <test name="dgf">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.ClientTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Of course, you can also extend your test case from PowerMockTestCase as told by Johan.

Comment: Hi Sunil, Welcome to stack overflow. For future reference, if you're going to paste XML or HTML (or any other code/language), make sure you mark it as code (editor button or ctrl-K) as otherwise it might not be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Mock all the static methods in static class before proceeding to mock the static method. Try with this:

```
@Test
 public void testMe() {
   PowerMock.mockStatic(Static.class);
   EasyMock.expect(Static.staticMethod()).andReturn("Mock called").anyTimes();
   PowerMock.replay(Static.class,staticClass);
   TargetClass tc = new TargetClass();
   String output = tc.callHere();
   PowerMock.verify(Static.class,staticClass);
   System.out.println(output);
 }
```