# How do you write a _spy_ for a (public) method of a final class using PowerMock/Mockito and TestNG?

Tags: java, testng, mockito, powermock

(yes, I know, some people consider having to resort to PowerMock admitting failure)

Hello,

Versions: TestNG 6.8, Mockito 1.9.5, and PowerMock 1.5.

Despite googling around for quite some time, I could not find an example of that.

The class in question, `SyntaxProcessor`, has a `process()` method which does a preliminary check, and if this check passes, it calls `validate()`.

Here, I make that preliminary check fail on purpose. And I want to check that `validate()` is indeed never called.

After help from @user1951544, I came up with:

```
@PrepareForTest(SyntaxProcessor.class)
public final class SyntaxProcessorTest
{
    // ....

    @ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory()
    {
        return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }

    // ....

    @DataProvider
    public Iterator<Object[]> notSchemas()
    {
        return SampleNodeProvider.getSamplesExcept(NodeType.OBJECT);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "notSchemas")
    public void syntaxProcessorYellsOnNonSchemas(final JsonNode node)
        throws ProcessingException
    {
        final ArgumentCaptor<ProcessingMessage> captor
            = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ProcessingMessage.class);

        final ProcessingReport report = PowerMockito.mock(ProcessingReport.class);
        final JsonSchemaTree tree = new CanonicalSchemaTree(node);
        final ValidationData data = new ValidationData(tree);

        final Map<String, SyntaxChecker> map = Maps.newHashMap();
        final SyntaxProcessor processor = PowerMockito.spy(new SyntaxProcessor(map));

        processor.process(report, data);

        // No PowerMockito.verify()??
        // "any()" is from org.mockito.Matchers
        Mockito.verify(processor, never())
            .validate(any(SyntaxReport.class), any(JsonSchemaTree.class));

        final JsonNode msgNode = captor.getValue().asJson();
        assertEquals(msgNode.get("message").textValue(),
            "document is not a JSON Schema: not an object");
    }
}
```

This test unfortunately fails with a humongous stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:143)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:426)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.<init>(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:17)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.filterStackTrace(MockitoException.java:30)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.<init>(MockitoException.java:19)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MockitoConfigurationException.<init>(MockitoConfigurationException.java:18)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.loadImplementations(ClassPathLoader.java:145)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.findPluginImplementation(ClassPathLoader.java:110)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.findPlatformMockMaker(ClassPathLoader.java:106)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.<clinit>(ClassPathLoader.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:21)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.scanner.MockScanner.<init>(MockScanner.java:22)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.injectMocks(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:96)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.configuration.PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.process(PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.java:38)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.injectSpiesAndInjectToSetters(AnnotationEnabler.java:58)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:2014)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:744)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:415)
    at org.powermock.modules.testng.internal.PowerMockTestNGMethodHandler.injectMocksUsingAnnotationEnabler(PowerMockTestNGMethodHandler.java:72)
    at org.powermock.modules.testng.internal.PowerMockTestNGMethodHandler.invoke(PowerMockTestNGMethodHandler.java:47)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.processing.syntax.SyntaxProcessorTest_$$_javassist_0.notSchemas(SyntaxProcessorTest_$$_javassist_0.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceFilter.<clinit>(StackTraceFilter.java:21)
    ... 56 more
```

I also tried, reading [this page](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/TestNG_usage), to make the test extend `PowerMockTestCase` instead, but then it fails with another error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't invoke method public void com.github.fge.jsonschema.processing.syntax.SyntaxProcessorTest.syntaxProcessorYellsOnNonSchemas(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode) throws com.github.fge.jsonschema.processing.ProcessingException, probably due to classloader mismatch
```

So, how do you write such a test?

(edit: also tried to downgrade versions of TestNG, mockito and powermock to versions suggested by @user1951544. It works for him, not for me... But this time I get the second, shorter exception in both scenarios)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with PowerMock, you have to add 2 annotations to you unit test:
@RunWith
@PrepareForTest
and then replace the Mockito's spy/mock methods with PowerMockito's.

You can find some usufull examples here:
http://www.smartics.de/archives/1233

The simplest test could look like that:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    public void test(){
        MyClass myClass = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());

        myClass.interfaceMethod(some arguments);
        Mockito.verify(myClass,Mockito.never()).otherMethod();              
    }

}
```

In case of TestNG a proper ObjectFactory has to be set (instead of @RunWith), as in example in http://almirsadikovic.blogspot.fr/2011/07/testng-and-powermockito-powermock.html or [Cant mock static functions with powermock-easymock-testng (non-maven project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633885/cant-mock-static-functions-with-powermock-easymock-testng-non-maven-project)

Comment: Uhm, TestNG has no @RunWith... Looking more.

Comment: I have missed that you are using TestNG, in that case you have to set the PowerMockObjectFactory as Object Factory, look for example in the:  http://almirsadikovic.blogspot.fr/2011/07/testng-and-powermockito-powermock.html or in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633885/cant-mock-static-functions-with-powermock-easymock-testng-non-maven-project

Comment: OK, there is "progress", now I am getting an NPE instead of Mockito yelling at me that it can't do final :p

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a workaround for the second problem.

It seems that there is some kind of problem with testng/powermock versions as described here:
http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=414

In my test case I changed powermock version to 1.4.11 and testng to 6.4 and everything works fine:)

tricky stuff...

Comment: Uh, I saw that page but didn't make the relationship... I'll try that

Comment: Eh, no, still the same error as in the second case... But this time, with either of the ObjectFactory or the extends. Argh!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to help with that, this might not be the best advice in context of testng, but maybe you could consider switching to junit?

Comment: And lose TestNG's @DataProvider? :p No ;)